# Stabilization of the second BVP solutions for nondivergence parabolic equations

Tags: reference-request, parabolic-pde

Let $Q\subset \mathbb R^n$ be  a bounded domain with smooth enough boundary $S$.
For a uniformly parabolic operator
$$
Lu=u_t-\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}(x)\partial_{ij}u-\sum_{i=1}^n b_{i}(x)\partial_{i}u
$$
with Holder continuous coefficients consider the second BVP
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
Lu&=&0\hbox{ in } \ Q\times(0,\infty),\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar n}\big|_{S\times(0,\infty)}&=&0,\\
u|_{t=0}&=&\psi\in C^{\infty}(\bar Q), 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where $\bar n$ is a unit normal to $S$. Is it true that the solution $u$ tends to a constant (which is a solution of the corresponding elliptic BVP) then $t\to+\infty$? For parabolic equations in divergence form there are many papers concerning stabilization of solutions even in unbounded domains, but I didn't manage to find such a result for non divergence equations.